# would number of extreme points of convex polygon shrink by union?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Given two Convex polygon $A$, $B$, denote their number of extreme points as $N(A), N(B)$.

One can obtain a bigger convex polygon by union $A, B$, and find the convex hull denote $C:= CH(A\cup B)$.

what's the relationship between $N(C)$ vs $N(A) + N(B)$, my gut feeling is $N(C) \leq N(A) +N(B)$  ?
and what's the lower bound of $N(C)$ in the sense of $N(A), N(B)$?

and do the results generalize to non-convex polygon?
and also do the result generalizes to convex polytope?

Comment: 1) $N(C) = N(A) + N(B)$ is possible. Take a square, remove a thin strip along one of its diagonal, you get two right triangles $A$ and $B$, the convex hull of $A \cup B$ is a hexagon! 2) $N(C)$ can be as low as $3$. Take an equilateral triangle, cut it along a median to get two right triangles. One each right triangles, replace the newly formed edge by a polygonal path which approximate a circle arc of large radius. Let $A$, $B$ be the resulting regions. $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ can be as large as you want while keeping $A \cup B = C$.

Comment: thanks! yeah, let me update the $\lt$ into $\leq$

Comment: and for the  lower bound of (), I was referring to in the sense of N(A) and N(B), not the absolute value

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "in the sense of $N(A)$ and $N(B)$". You can have $N(A) = N(B) = 10^6$ while $N(C) = 3$....

Comment: right... so basically N(C) can't be lower bounded by N(A) and N(B). for 1) can we prove that the $ N(C) \leq N(A) + N(B) $ ?

Comment: why is  "Since every point in  can be written as convex linear combination of vertices of  and ," ?

Comment: A better argument. For any $p \in C$, if  $p \not\in A \cup B$, then $p = \alpha a + (1-\alpha) b$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1), a \in A$ and $b \in B$. This means such $p$ cannot be an extreme point. If $p \in A$, then it cannot be extreme unless it is one of $A$'s vertices. Same thing happens when $p \in B$. This means the only candidates for extreme points are vertices of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: 1) The set of points that can be written as convex linear combination of vertices of $A$ and $B$ is convex. 2) This set contains $A$ and $B$ 2) Every convex set that contain $A$ and $B$ need to contain the set in (1) and 4) By definition, the convex hull of $A$ and $B$ is the smallest convex set containing them.

Comment: thank you! do you mind make that as an answer? I'm happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to show $N(C) \le N(A) + N(B)$ in general.

For any $p \in C$, we have either $p \in A \cup B$ or $\not\in A \cup B$.

**Case I** - $p \not\in A\cup B$.

In this case, I claim

> there is an $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $p = \alpha a + (1-\alpha) b$

To see why this is true, consider the set of points
$$C' \stackrel{def}{=} \{ \alpha a + (1-\alpha) b : \alpha \in [0,1], a \in A, b \in B \}$$

It is not hard to see

- $A \subset C'$ (by taking $\alpha= 1$) and $B \subset C'$ (by taking $\alpha = 0$).
- $C'$ is convex.
- Every convex set contains $A$ and $B$ contains $C'$.

Since by definition $C$ is the smallest convex set containing $A$ and $B$, this forces $C = C'$.

This implies we can find an $\alpha \in [0,1], a \in A, b \in B$ such that $p = \alpha a + (1-\alpha) b$. Now $\alpha$ cannot be $0$ because $p \not\in B$ and cannot be $1$ because $p \not\in A$. This justifies above claim.

Next, choose a small positive $\epsilon < \min( \alpha, 1 - \alpha )$, we find $p$ is the mid point of two points $(\alpha \pm \epsilon ) a + (1 - \alpha \mp \epsilon ) b \in C$. This means $p$ cannot be an extreme point.

**Case II** - $p \in A \cup B \implies p \in A \lor p \in B$.

If $p \in A$ but not an vertex of $A$, it is not an extreme point of $A$ and hence cannot be an extreme point of the larger set $C$.
By a similar argument, when $p \in B$ but not an vertex of $B$, $p$ cannot be an extreme point of $C$.

Combine these two cases, we find there are at most $N(A) + N(B)$ candidates of extreme points of $C$. Namely, the vertices of $A$ and $B$. From this, we can deduce
$$N(C) \le N(A) + N(B)$$

Comment: I think your argument leads to a stronger result: the extreme points of $C$ are a subset of the union of the extreme points of $A$ and the extreme points of $B$.